# LDAP query from Excel VBA to Google Sheets function

Tags: function, excel, google-sheets, vba

Can anyone explain how this function - currently used in Excel VBA - can be translated to Google Scripts for use with a Sheets function? I am having trouble searching for help on this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Function CoreID_from_EmployeeID(CommerceID)
CoreID_from_EmployeeID = "Error"
 Set objDirectory = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDirectory.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
    objDirectory.Open "ADs Provider"

    Set objDirectoryResults = objDirectory.Execute("<LDAP://ids.company.com/ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=company,dc=com>;(CommerceID=" + CStr(CommerceID) + ");CoreID;subtree")

    If objDirectoryResults.EOF = False Then
     CoreID_from_EmployeeID = objDirectoryResults.Fields.Item("CoreID").Value
     Else
     CoreID_from_EmployeeID = "Not Found"
    End If
End Function
```